# Attribute Error: 'dict' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Tags: python, django

```
(y) xlm@d8cb8a102c73:~/workspace/y-server/y$ ./manage.py 
 run_algorithm --settings=y.settings.local
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/xlm/.virtualenvs/y/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in 
execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/xlm/.virtualenvs/y/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 346, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/xlm/.virtualenvs/y/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 394, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/xlm/.virtualenvs/y/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 454, in execute
    self.stdout.write(output)
  File "/home/xlm/.virtualenvs/y/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 111, in write
    if ending and not msg.endswith(ending):
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

I am trying to run the file algorithm.py with the command file run_algorithm.py (below) on a django framework. However I get the above attribute error, and I am unsure why.

```
import logging
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from ...algorithm import engagement_level_mapping
logger = logging.getLogger(settings.LOGGER_NAME)


class Command(BaseCommand):
     help = "TODO: describe"
     def handle(self, *args, **options):
        result = engagement_level_mapping()
        return result
```

However, when printing the result, rather than returning, the file executes correctly.

```
import logging
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from ...algorithm import engagement_level_mapping
logger = logging.getLogger(settings.LOGGER_NAME)


class Command(BaseCommand):
     help = "TODO: describe"
     def handle(self, *args, **options):
        result = engagement_level_mapping()
        print(result)
```

The command file prints a dictionary of engagement values for each user (not that relevant, but just that it prints a dictionary).

Here is the code in base.py

Comment: `if ending and not msg.endswith(ending):` code for this?

Comment: Are you supposed to return anything in the handle function? The django document does not show anything to be returned.

Answer (score 7):

You get this error because a django management command's `handle()` method is not supposed to return anything but a string -if you read the traceback, you easily find out that the error happens in the base class (in django/core/management/base.pydjango/core/management/base.py), which tries to print out the value returned by your command.

The point is that is makes no sense returning anything else from a management command: a management command is a command-line tool and is expected either to work by side effects (modifying something in your database / on your filesystem / etc) or to generate some text output that can be either displayed or fed to another command line program (in the unix tradition where you pipe commands together).

The fix is plain obvious: format your result as a string before returning it, ie (example with a json output but you could choose to generate csv or xml or whatever suits you):

```
import json

class Command(BaseCommand):
     help = "TODO: describe"
     def handle(self, *args, **options):
        result = engagement_level_mapping()
        return json.dumps(result, indent=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error we can infer that you are checking a `dict` instead of a `string` in your `if condition`. Check the value assigned for `msg` variable.

Comment: The error happens in Django's own code, not the OP's.

Answer (score 0):

Use your stack traces. The stack trace tells you exactly where the error occured and why. In yours, it says that it's on `line 111` in `File "/home/xlm/.virtualenvs/y/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/django/core/management/base.py"`. From what the details say, it looks like you have a variable `msg` that you expect to be a string (I assume this because it is called with a method that is a string method.

However, it also looks like this is a django block of code in the django framework. This means that you are calling a method that eventually calls that code. I assume that you are suppose to pass in a string but instead you pass in a dictionary.

So look around for code that results in that traceback (We can't here because we don't have your entire project and the code you gave us isn't it) and check the value you are trying to pass in.